# How to obtain cursor from a Sqlite database created using ORM?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, cursor

Is it possible to get the cursor if I created the database using ORM? I have searched the web but the only examples I could find were that of using SQLiteOpenHelper to get the cursor. It is for passing into a CursorAdapter to attach the database to a listview.

Comment: ORM? what ORM? there are plenty of them for android

Comment: Sorry it's Sqlite.Net ORM

Comment: rhis one https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs ?

Comment: @pskink yes, that's the one

Comment: never used but if you try to ^F `Cursor` you will find out that there is nothing related to `Android.Database.ICursor`

Comment: ah..oh well worth a try. I guess I'll have to explore other options. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORMLite
in this you can use

```
getDatabaseHelper().getReadableDatabase().query();
```

or

getDatabaseHelper().getWritableDatabase().query();

But you have take care of locking  in case on mutlithreaded application.